# Email Invitation for complete registration using asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement user invitation using asp.net Identity in my application, the users need to be invited by an Admin rather than start the registration themselves. So in my invitation process, I create a user without a password, adding the correct role and send an email with GenerateUserTokenAsync. So far so good. (open for suggestion tho)

My concerns are:
After the user clicks in the link he/she received by email, it goes to a View I created, but I wonder if it would be better to re-use one of the Identity Pages, Confirme Email Registration for example, or the registration itself.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if you want to reuse Email confirm page,  you could try to use identity confirm page razor page as below. Besides, I suggest you could try to redirect the user to change passwork page to change the password.

You need to generate the Email link with two querystring parameters, userId and code. More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ConfirmEmailModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public ConfirmEmailModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
        }

        code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
        var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
        StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? "Thank you for confirming your email." : "Error confirming your email.";
        return Page();
    }
}
```